# How to create a code to get correlations for each "varieties" in a colonm?

Tags: r

I'm still a debutant with R so this is my issue.

I got a dataframe named dataset3.

```
structure(list(Varietes = c("Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Ruby", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone", "Abelastone"), ligne.rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pied = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7), Date.floraison.mâle = structure(c(1627689600, 1627430400, 1627689600, 1627344000,1627516800,1627603200, 1627689600, 1627516800, 1627776000, 1627603200, 1627344000,1627516800, 1627689600, 1627776000, 1627516800, 1627862400, 1627776000, 1627948800, 1628035200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Date.floraison.femelle = structure(c(1627776000, 1627948800, 1627862400, 1627948800, 1628121600, 1628035200, 1627862400, 1627862400, 1628035200,1628121600, 1627862400, 1627948800, 1628380800, 1628121600, 1628553600, 1629158400, 1628640000, 1629849600, 1629158400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), ASIi = c(1, 6, 2, 7, 7, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 5, 8, 4, 12, 15, 10, 22, 13), Hauteur.des.pieds = c(200, 210, 205, 215, 217, 207, 205, 208, 206, 215, 216, 212, 220, 215, 230, 228, 226, 240, 233), Hauteur.des.soies = c(100, 104, 102, 110, 108, 103, 102, 105, 105, 110, 112, 108, 113, 110, 123, 118, 116, 124, 122)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`6` = 6L, `10` = 10L, `20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, `24` = 24L), class = "omit"))
```

This is false data. I'm trying now to write a script that will be really helpful in the futur.

I would like to interroge my data to the simpliest way possible to get correltions, like for example "ASIi" and "Hauteur des pieds", but for each varieties of my column "Varietes". In my dataset 3 i got 3 varieties : Georgia, Abelastone, Ruby.

Because in my real dataset i will have 50 varieties and this will not easy if i have to isolate every variety.

Is there an easier way to do this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get the correlation of the same variable, but for each variety**

We can loop trough every combination of two varieties:

```
comb.var = combn(unique(dataset3$Varietes), 2) #Get the combinations

correlations = list() #Create empty list to store values
cols = c("Pied", "ASIi", "Hauteur.des.pieds", "Hauteur.des.soies") #Define the columns that you want to get correlations for

for(i in 1:ncol(comb.var)){
  name = paste(comb.var[,i], collapse="/")
  correlations[[name]] = numeric() #Create a empty vector for the combination
  for(j in cols){
    correlations[[name]][j] = cor(dataset3[dataset3$Varietes==comb.var[1,i],j],
                                  dataset3[dataset3$Varietes==comb.var[2,i],j])}} #Fill the vector with each correlation
```

OBS: your example data had less observations for `Abelastone`, if in your real dataset every variety has the same amount of obs this won't be a problem, otherwise i can generalize the code a bit more. Output:

```
> correlations
$`Georgia/Ruby`
             Pied              ASIi Hauteur.des.pieds Hauteur.des.soies 
        0.9787781         0.1828599         0.1065409         0.3239701 

$`Georgia/Abelastone`
             Pied              ASIi Hauteur.des.pieds Hauteur.des.soies 
        0.9048705         0.6451144         0.5370488         0.3387600 

$`Ruby/Abelastone`
             Pied              ASIi Hauteur.des.pieds Hauteur.des.soies 
       0.93982306        0.05192741        0.44198418        0.21908902
```

**To get the correlation of different variables, for each variety**

We just reverse the logic of the loop:

```
comb.col = combn(cols, 2)

for(i in 1:ncol(comb.col)){
  name = paste(comb.col[,i], collapse="/")
  correlations[[name]] = numeric()
  for(j in unique(dataset3$Varietes)){
    correlations[[name]][j] = cor(dataset3[[comb.col[1,i]]][dataset3$Varietes==j],
                                  dataset3[[comb.col[2,i]]][dataset3$Varietes==j])}}
```

Output:

```
> correlations
$`ASIi/Hauteur.des.pieds`
   Georgia       Ruby Abelastone 
 0.9340590  0.8795120  0.8174805 

$`ASIi/Hauteur.des.soies`
   Georgia       Ruby Abelastone 
 0.8849296  0.8489775  0.5125693 

$`Hauteur.des.pieds/Hauteur.des.soies`
   Georgia       Ruby Abelastone 
 0.9519358  0.9789882  0.8293315
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's not what exactly what i'm looking for. AS you can see, in my data i have 3 differents varieties. I would like for this 3 differents varieties examine correlations of differents variables like "ASIi" and "hauteur des pieds" and for each varieties. If i understood well this code allow me to have correlation of variables between varieties.

Comment: So you want (for example) the cor(ASIi, Hauteur des pieds), but calculated for each of the variables?

Comment: So  I want (for example) the cor(ASIi, Hauteur des pieds), but calculated for each of the variables "Varietes", so in my dataset Georgia, Abelastone, Ruby. Really thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! I added a second part to my answer, does it get you what you want?

Comment: Yes thank you very much you are a boss, this will be really helpful in my work. Forget my last message ahah im just a debutant i forget to run the cols ahah

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer to mark the post as solved then.